# Pylint flags whitespace incorrectly; disagrees with PEP8

Tags: python-3.x, code-analysis, pylint, pep8

Pylint flags this line 4 times for bad whitespace:

```
def __init__(self, file_id: int = None, filetype_id: int = None,
             module_id: int = None, file_name: str = None):
```

Message:

```
C:  7, 0: No space allowed around keyword argument assignment
    def __init__(self, file_id: int = None, filetype_id: int = None,
                                    ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  7, 0: No space allowed around keyword argument assignment
    def __init__(self, file_id: int = None, filetype_id: int = None,
                                                             ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  8, 0: No space allowed around keyword argument assignment
                 module_id: int = None, file_name: str = None):
                                ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  8, 0: No space allowed around keyword argument assignment
                 module_id: int = None, file_name: str = None):
                                                       ^ (bad-whitespace)
```

But in PEP8 it says

> When combining an argument annotation with a default value, use spaces
>   around the = sign (but only for those arguments that have both an
>   annotation and a default).

This just makes sense, as it would look ridiculous to write `def func(arg: int=4)`. This looks more than assigning 4 to int than assigning 4 to arg.

This error makes up the majority of any pylint analysis. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: This is a known issue (https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/238). Nobody got time to deal with it, yet. One way to disable this error is across the board, using ``pylint --disable=bad-whitespace``, at least until the issue gets a fix.

Comment: It's already fixed in the master for the upcomming 2.0 version, see [PR #1229](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/1229), but unfortunately not in the stable release 1.6.5.